# jquery ui sortable: element width calculated too small

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RqE2p/

There is a list of `sortable()` inline text elements. The elements are "number one", "number two", ...etc. The problem with some of them (in my case e.g. "number  five" and "number two", but it depends on current browser zoom I think) is that as soon as I start dragging it, the second word goes to the second line.

That's because the width of the element changes while dragging. In Chrome Inspector, Computed Styles, the "number five" width before dragging is 75.19999px. As soon as dragging starts, the computed width is 75px. So, the second word doesn't fit into the first line anymore.

For this example, I have problem only in Chrome. But in real life project, this happens in FF, too. I don't know, why in this example all is ok in FF.

Is there any simple method to deal with this, other than maybe making a javascript loop and setting each sortable element's css width to 1.1 times its current width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust it directly with CSS without having to dabble in JavaScript:
The simplest solution would be to set a height for your ul lis and set no-wrap to make sure the text stays neatly on one line:

```
ul li {
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This should solve your problem :) Enjoy using sortable!

EDIT: Can you give more details; if the lis are set to white-space: nowrap; your text shouldn't go to a second line unless the CSS is being overwritten. If it is add an important tag to your white-space: nowrap; (eg. white-space: nowrap!important;). It's working on Chrome zoomed in 110 + %

Comment: I am sorry, it *does* work, actually. I must have made some mistake testing it. Thanks for the extra simple solution :)